# WooCommerce add_to_cart() FAILS if cart is NOT empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a fairly simple function that gets several products data and bulk-adds those products to the cart via a foreach loop. **The problem** is that, if the cart already contains any product added, the first product in my loop is skipped and not added. Any other products after the first one, get added no problem. If the cart IS empty, all products get added no problem, including the first one.

**I have recreated the problem using a clean installation.** I have only WooCommerce and Code Snippets activated. You can see the behaviour at this [/sample-page/](http://magikprintsforyou.com/sample-page/) clicking the "Add All to Cart" button. It will work for the first time, but if you reload and click again, the problem will appear.

```
add_shortcode( 'add-all-to-cart', 'add_all_to_cart_shortcode' );

function add_all_to_cart_shortcode() {
    global $woocommerce;
    ob_start();
    ?>
        <form id="add-all-to-cart" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="add-all-to-cart-button" class="add-all button alt">Add all to cart</button>
        </form>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_all_to_cart_handler' );
function add_all_to_cart_handler() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( isset( $_POST['add-all-to-cart-button'] ) ) {
        $products_data = array(
            array(
                'product_id' => 18,
                'variation_id' => 19,
                'quantity' => 1
            ),
            array(
                'product_id' => 21,
                'variation_id' => 22,
                'quantity' => 1
            ),
            array(
                'product_id' => 24,
                'variation_id' => 26,
                'quantity' => 1
            )
        );

        foreach ( $products_data as $product ) {
            $product_id = $product['product_id'];
            $variation_id = $product['variation_id'];
            $quantity = $product['quantity'];
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id );
        }
        wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_cart_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
```

**What I've tried:**

I've dumped all variables and all data is good, all integers. I tried checking the `cart_item_key` and it is being correctly assigned. I tried changing the code to first look for any given product already in cart and just update their quantity, but that did not solved the problem. Also tried throwing some `WC()->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies();` statements in there, but to no luck.

Searching for answers I found some people talking about cart sessions and the persistent cart. But I am unsure if this is related.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531798/hooks-around-add-to-cart-for-woocommerce it may lead you down the correct path. It seems like some sort of validation of the existing cart is necessary.

Comment: Thans for the suggestion. I did indeed tried a bit with woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation, as suggested in the answer by LoicTheAztec, but I had no luck. I am not sure this is it, tho, because all the other products add alright to the cart, only the first one fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Init hook is called way to earlier and missed the actual job in your code.

Replace `init` hook with `template_redirect` hook when you call `add_all_to_cart_handler` function.

Comment: That was it. Thank you, Saqib. I've accepted your answer as correct.